# How to send .caf file via email in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send an audio file with .caf extension via email in iphone. Can anyone help me to do this? I have written `mimeType:@"audio/caf"` but I think it is not supporting that. Please help me to do this small task.

Comment: do you have the code on how you are doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code :-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:memo.memoUrl];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filepath];  
NSData *dataToSend = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
[fileURL release];

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Recording"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = nil;
NSArray *ccRecipients = nil; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = nil;

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

[picker setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
[picker addAttachmentData:dataToSend mimeType:@"audio/x-caf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"voice-memo.caf", memo.memoName]];
```

Comment: Yeah..i have used mimetype:@"audio/caf" and my mistake was i have not written .caf extension after file name.. Once i have appended .caf extension after file name it started working.. :) By the way thanks.